# Django rest_framework serializer with inner relationship

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Here part of my **models.py:**

```
class Discount(models.Model):
    discount_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    discount_category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    discount_store = models.ManyToManyField(Store)
    ...

class Store(models.Model):
    store_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    store_company =models.ForeignKey('Company')
    store_city = models.ForeignKey('City', to_field='city_name')
    ....
```

Here part of my **serializer.py:**,

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Store
    fields = ('store_location', 'store_city', 'store_name', 'store_address')


class DiscountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Discount
        fields = ('discount_description', 'discount_start', 'discount_end', discount_title', 'discount_category', 'discount_store')
```

When I create JSON for discount I get this JSON.

```
[{
    "discount_description": "Description here.",
    "discount_start": "2014-08-07T14:35:13Z",
    "discount_end": "2014-08-30T14:35:15Z",
    "discount_title": "Lorem İpsum",
    "discount_category": [
        3
    ],
    "discount_store": [
        1
    ]
}]
```

But I want to see store details in "discount_store". I tried a lot of relationship for this. But all the time I get this JSON.

Comment: After I renamed the foreign key column name in table definition as the above, it was starting to pick up. I think it's better to override the default foreign key column name and give something like store_city (in this case it will be store_city_id in the database after migration) which can be mentioned in serializers class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to add the option `depth` to the Meta class? Maybe like this:

```
class DiscountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Discount
        fields = ('discount_description', 'discount_start', 'discount_end', 'discount_title', 'discount_category', 'discount_store')
        depth = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I tried every relationship in serializer. But solution is depth option. I don't understand why. By the way can you add single qoute beginning of "discount_title"?

Comment: I added the missing single quote before `discount title`. You're right, I should be more careful when copying other people's code. The option `depth` is explained in the official documentation of DRF. It would be also possible to use another number but 1, if the model structure is deeper and there is a need to show additional information.

Comment: After your first comment I read rest_framework documentation. Not I got it. If I had another relationship in Store, I could use depth=2. Thank you for fast response.