# Django Rest Framework: how do I Display content of Foreign keys in JSON

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have serialised a model into JSON that has foreign keys. The API will show the title of the foreign key but will not nest the data that belongs to that foreign key. How do I do this.

serializers.py

```
class ReportFieldSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    form = serializers.RelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = ReportField
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
            'form'
        )
```

api.py

```
class ReportFieldList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        report_field = ReportField.objects.all()
        serialized_report_field = ReportFieldSerializers(report_field, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_report_field.data)

class ReportFieldDetail(APIView):
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return ReportField.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except ReportField.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        report_field = self.get_object(pk)
        serialized_report_field = ReportFieldSerializers(report_field)
        return Response(serialized_report_field.data)
```

models.py

```
class Report(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    form = models.ForeignKey()

class Form(models.Model):
    # Form details
```

Comment: You have ReportField in your serializers.py, but a model Report in your models.py. Can you please correct that to reflect your actual code.

Answer (score 6):

There is an option `depth`, that can be used in the Meta class of the serializer. For example:

```
class ReportFieldSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ReportField
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
            'form'
        )
        depth = 1
```

This will go one step down in the related models. As you see you don't need the `RelatedField`. If, let's say, there would be a third model class, for example:

```
class Form(models.Model):
    example = ForeignKey('AnotherModel')

class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    # model fields
```

you could also use `depth=2` in your `ReportFieldSerializer` to display the information for this model.

I assume that in your model `Report` the field `form` shows to `Form`: `models.ForeignKey(Form)`.

I answered already a similar question here:
[Django rest_framework serializer with inner relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181729/django-rest-framework-serializer-with-inner-relationship/25197367#25197367)

Comment: This helped me. Is it possible to remove the `id` field of the foreign key altogether? Or am looking at it the wrong way? I'm new to django, I was thinking it defeats the purpose of hiding the `id` field on the foreign model's serializer if it will be just displayed as well if taken from the other object. Is there a reason that i'm missing? Is it perhaps for accessing?