# Django, DRF (& React) Foreign key, how to display the name value instead of the foreign key id

Tags: django, reactjs, django-models, django-rest-framework

There are two Django models - ClientCompany & Proposal and the foreign key of ClientCompany is within the Proposal model. In Proposal how do I display the name of the ClientCompany instead of the foreign key id?

models.py:

```js
class ClientCompany(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Client Name", max_length=255)
    abn_acn = models.BigIntegerField("ABN / ACN")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Proposal(models.Model):
    proj_name = models.CharField("Project Name", max_length=255)
    loc_state = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
    )
    proj_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
    )
    prop_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
    )
    client = models.ForeignKey(ClientCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    oneic = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='main_engineer')
    twoic = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='second_engineer')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.proj_name
```

serializers.py:

```js
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ClientCompany
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'abn_acn')


class ProposalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Proposal
        fields = ('id', 'proj_name', 'loc_state', 'proj_type', 'prop_status', 'client', 'oneic', 'twoic',)
```

queryset api.py:

```js
class ProposalViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]
    queryset = Proposal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProposalSerializer
```

currently[shows the client foreign key id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJxoz.png)

I've been stuck on this, tried to apply the existing solutions recommended for similar problems but had no luck... if someone can tell me what I'm missing - thanks

Comment: try depth = 2 in model meta, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718636/django-rest-framework-how-do-i-display-content-of-foreign-keys-in-json

Answer (score 1):

Update your serializer like this:

```
class ProposalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = ClientSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Proposal
        fields = ('id', 'proj_name', 'loc_state', 'proj_type', 'prop_status', 'client', 'oneic', 'twoic',)
```

Comment: thanks for replying but I encountered this error:
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, abn_acn}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @tangnology Its because client's value is a dictionary inside the list of proposals in ReactJs. If you just want the name of client, you can check the update section of my answer.

Comment: @tangnology if you want to use just the name, then your answer is most appropriate. But can you try to get the `client` in react by using `proposalObject.client.name`(where proposalObject is the the proposal object sent via API)?

Answer (score 1):

I found this worked in the end by adding the serializers.SlugRelatedField line in serializers.py:

```js
class ProposalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    client = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="name", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Proposal
        fields = ('id', 'proj_name', 'loc_state', 'proj_type', 'prop_status',
                  'client', 'oneic', 'twoic',)
```